# get product image url from getItemsCollection

Tags: magento-1.7, collection, image

I'am trying to get the image product url from getItemsCollection generated by Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed. Here is my code. Everything is working except getImageUrl()

```
$nb = 3;
$already_used = array();
$collection = Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed')->getItemsCollection();
foreach ($collection as $item){
    if ($nb > 0)
    {
        ?>
        <div class="product">
            <div class="image_product">
                <a href="<?php echo $item->getProductUrl(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $item->getImageUrl(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->getName();?>" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="title_product">
                <h3><a href="<?php echo $item->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $item->getName(); ?></a></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        $already_used[] = (int)$item->getProductId();
    }
    $nb--;
}
```

I don't understand what is wrong in my code...

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2):

`$item` should be an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` so you should be able to get the image url using the catalog image helper:

```
$imageUrl = (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item, 'image');
```

**[EDIT]**
So your code should look like this (only the section that should display the image)

```
<div class="image_product">
    <a href="<?php echo $item->getProductUrl(); ?>">
       <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item, 'image')/*->resize(200, 200)*/; ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->getName();?>" />
    </a>
</div>
```

If you want the image at a specific size, just uncomment the `resize` method and change the width and height.

Comment: I understand but the product list I want is the last viewed product. Do you know how to adapt my current code for that purpose ?

Comment: @axelparatre. See my update.

Comment: I try it but it's not working

Answer (score 2):

I find a solution based on that I found on the Internet.

Add this line after if($nb > 0) { :

```
$Products_one = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
```

Than change the code bellow :

```
<div class="image_product">
                <a href="<?php echo $item->getProductUrl(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $Products_one->getImageUrl(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->getName();?>" /></a>
            </div>
```

Do you think it's an acceptable solution in term of performance ?

Answer (score 2):

I know that almost the same answer already exist but try instead of 'image' use 'small_image'

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($item, 'small_image')->resize(135) ?>
```

That code is used everywhere where is used `Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed`.